# How to get the "Created" or "Signed In" information with user.info object?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

How can I have in the object returned by the method `signInWithEmailAndPassword` the information for Created or Signed In (last time connected) in Firebase?

[image]

Comment: That type of metadata is not exposed in the client SDK.